# The method onReceive in BroadcastReceiver is never called

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver

My task is to turn the Bluetooth ON & OFF from my app and then search for any paired devices. If any paired device is found, connect to it; otherwise, discover the available devices in vicinity and list them along with their signal strengths; update these signals strengths every N seconds. When the user selects a particular device, connection should be established.

```
package surendra.example.com.mybluetooth;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.BlackLevelPattern;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static final int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;

    private BluetoothDevice device;

    //Variable for text display
    public TextView statusUpdate;
    public TextView BTHostDetails;
    public TextView BTDevicesAvailable;

    //List of buttons
    public Button turnONBT;
    public Button turnOFFBT;
    public Button scanBTDevices;
    public Button seeRSSI;
    public Button back;

    ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
    //BluetoothAdapter object that initializes the BT hardware on the device
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    //Broadcast the Bluetooth activities
    BroadcastReceiver bluetoothState = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String prevStateExtra  = BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE;
            String stateExtra = BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE;

            int state = intent.getIntExtra(stateExtra, -1);
            int previousState = intent.getIntExtra(prevStateExtra, -1);

            String toastText = "";

            switch (state) {
                case(BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON) : {
                    //Already turned ON
                    toastText = "Turning ON Bluetooth";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case(BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON): {
                    //Turned ON
                    toastText = "Bluetooth turned ON";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setupUI();
                    break;
                }
                case(BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF) : {
                    //Already turned OFF
                    toastText = "Turning OFF Bluetooth";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case(BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) : {
                    //Turned OFF
                    toastText = "Bluetooth turned OFF";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setupUI();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //Represents a remote BT device
    private BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get default BT adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        setupUI();
    } //end onCreate method

    //Method to setup UI
    private void setupUI() {
        //Get references of each button and text view from the UI
        final TextView statusUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusUpdate);
        final TextView BTHostDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BTHostDetails);
        final Button turnONBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turnONBT);
        final Button turnOFFBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turnOFFBT);
        final Button scanBTDevices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanBTDevices);
        final Button seeRSSI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seeRSSI);
        final Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        //Set visibilities of each button
        turnOFFBT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        seeRSSI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        scanBTDevices.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        BTHostDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //Check if the BT adapter is enabled
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

            //If the BT adapter is enabled, get the name & address of the device
            String devName = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
            String devAddr = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();

            String statusText = devName + " : " + devAddr;
            BTHostDetails.setText(statusText);

            //set the visibilities of the buttons based upon BT status
            BTHostDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            turnONBT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            turnOFFBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            seeRSSI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scanBTDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            String tmp = "Bluetooth turned OFF";
            statusUpdate.setText(tmp);
        }

        // We should keep on listening to the TURN ON BLUETOOTH button.
        // When the button turn on bluetooth is clicked, we should proceed to turn Bluetooth ON
        turnONBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //This makes our device discoverable
                String beDiscoverable = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE;

                //Intent is the pop up that we see when requesting for permission to use
                //certain interface on the device just like permission for location access etc.
                //Using the intent filter, we can filter the devices whose permissions are changed
                //when the user updates on the intent
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

                //This registers a broadcast receiver
                registerReceiver(bluetoothState, filter);

                //If the intent changes from non-discoverable to discoverable, with the filter
                // DISCOVERY_REQUEST, then start the activity.
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(beDiscoverable), DISCOVERY_REQUEST);

                //Change the buttons views
                BTHostDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                turnOFFBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                turnONBT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                scanBTDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                seeRSSI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                String tmp = "Bluetooth turned ON";
                statusUpdate.setText(tmp);
            }
        });

        //scan devices
        scanBTDevices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //start discovery of new devices
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

                //see if this device is in a list of paired available devices
                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Debug text 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    //This means that there are paired devices.
                    // Get the name & address of each device.
                    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                        String devName = device.getName();
                        String devAddr = device.getAddress();
                    }

                    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
                        s.add(bt.getName());
                    }
                }
                BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        String action = intent.getAction();

                        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                            //BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                            short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
                            String devName = device.getName();
                            String devAddr = device.getAddress();

                            String tmp = devName + " : " + devAddr + " - " + rssi;
                            statusUpdate.setText(tmp);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        //Setup a listener for turning of Bluetooth i.e., for TURN OFF BLUETOOTH button
        turnOFFBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Change the buttons views
                BTHostDetails.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                turnOFFBT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                turnONBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                scanBTDevices.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                seeRSSI.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                String tmp = "Bluetooth turned OFF";
                statusUpdate.setText(tmp);

                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }
        });

        //Back button activity
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setupUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
            String tmp = "Discovery is in progress";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tmp , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setupUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Upon debug, I found that the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver is never called. However, Bluetooth is enabled. What am I missing?

PS: I want to confine all the BT activities into MainActivity alone.

Comment: You have two `BroadcastReceivers`. You only have one `registerReceiver()` call.

Comment: That would be really very helpful, if you can tell me how to manage this for my specifications, as this is the first ever code I'm doing either in Java or Android. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Upon debug, I found that the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver is never called. However, Bluetooth is enabled.

First, if Bluetooth is enabled, and nothing is changing the state of Bluetooth, I would not expect to receive any broadcast. The `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast [is documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) to be sent when "The state of the local Bluetooth adapter has been changed." No changes means no broadcast.

Second, you only register `bluetoothState` as a `BroadcastReceiver` if the user clicks `turnONBT`. So, if there is a state change before that, you would not receive the broadcast.

Third, you register `bluetoothState` for the wrong action. You are registering it for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`. That action is for Bluetooth discovery, as is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_FOUND). The action for changes in the Bluetooth state is `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`. Your `discoveryResult` would seem to be for discovery, and you never seem to register that receiver.

> as this is the first ever code I'm doing either in Java or Android

I would *not* recommend anything involving Bluetooth be your first project in Java or Android.

Comment: Can you mention any solution for the second point you've mentioned?

Comment: @surendranath: Register it at some other point, such as directly in `onCreate()`.